# How to store connection string in WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that consists of two forms. One form displays data returned from the database in fields and the other form opens a windows that allows the user to select which database to get the data from.

Currently, the application doesn't store the user's choice of database. I want to store what the currently selected connection string is each time the user selects the database they want to use in form2.

What is the best way to do this? If I made an instance of an object of a static class to store this information, would that persist the data for use on each form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there are built-in .NET capabilites to store user related information (via Registry, config files, settings etc.) they seem to be too heavy.

I would recommend to use plain text file and keep it in user folder:

```
var userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment
                                             .SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var filename = Path.Combine(userPath, "mysettings");

// Read connection string
var connectionString = File.ReadAllText(filename);

// Write connection string
File.WriteAllText(filename, connectionString);
```

Also note that hardly users will have fun working with connection strings. They would prefer to specify database name, server, username etc. using separate form fields. To map those fields to connection string you may use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class (if you are working with MSSQL Server):

```
// to connection string
var connectionStringBuilder1 = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionStringBuilder1.DataSource = "server";
connectionStringBuilder1.InitialCatalog = "database";
var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder1.ConnectionString;

// from connection string
var connectionStringBuilder2 = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var serverName = connectionStringBuilder2.DataSource;
var databaseName = connectionStringBuilder2.InitialCatalog;
```

Comment: If I was going to store the details in a text file, would I then take each setting of the SQLConnectionStringBuilder and put it on one line separated by ';'? (to make the whole connection string)

Comment: No, things are much simpler. Just use `var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder1.ConnectionString;`

Comment: You could use Isolated storage, that would work in more restricted environment

Answer (score 8):

You should have an `app.config` configuration file, and in there, define a `<connectionStrings>` section:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="YourNameHere" 
            connectionString="server=.;database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You then add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project, and then you can easily retrieve those connection strings:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourNameHere"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
   // do something here....
}
```

Comment: This solution wouldn't allow to change connection string by user while application is running -- even if configuration file is modified, application should be restarted to apply changes.

Comment: @the_joric: actually - you **can** modify an app.config file at runtime. By default, the .NET configuration system just doesn't load the config again, at runtime - only at startup.

Comment: Nice, but I did not say that you cannot modify a .config file :)

Answer (score 5):

You could store the connection string in `App.config` and retrieve it like this:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
```

Example `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
<configuration>    
    <configSections>    
    </configSections>    
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="Microsoft.SqlClient" />    
 </connectionStrings>    
</configuration>
```

Comment: The same problem as with @marc_s answer

Answer (score 4):

I would be tempted to use Application Settings for this purpose.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

This is a recommended place to keep your connection strings :-)